# How can I import resources to serverless managed project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, serverless

I am using `serverless` to deploy AWS resources. And sometimes I get an error about how there is an existing resources so the deploy failed. This could be caused by another developer in the team deploy the resources which have a conflict name. I wonder how I should handle this in `serverless`?

I used `terraform` before and it supports `import` command which is used to import existing resource to my project. Is there anything similar in `serverless`? If not, what is the best practise to solve this issue? I don't want to manually delete the resources on AWS.

Comment: I thought your question was about how to do https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html using serverless. The accepted answer does not address that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Importing CloudFormation resources is not supported by the serverless framework. But there are ways to solve the problem in question.

Serverless allows you to use **values** of existing CloudFormation resources. A pre-requisite is that your colleague or at least the CloudFormation stack describes the resource you depend on as ["output"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html).

```yaml
// in your colleagues serverless.yaml to export a VPC
resources:
   // ...
   Outputs:
     StackVPC:
       Description: The ID of the VPC
       Value: !Ref MyVPC
       Export:
         Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-VPCID"
```

In your *serverless.yaml* you can import/reference the existing VPC. There are a few [ways to import the resource](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-cloudformation-outputs) into your stack.

```yaml
var1: 'Fn::ImportValue': '${refSackName}-VPCID'
var2: ${cf:${refSackName}-VPCID}
```

For me, I mostly use [`Fn::ImportValue`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)

Pros and cons about this approach are listed here https://dev.to/lambdasharp/dynamic-bindings-for-cloudformation-stacks-15l6

Comment: the question is for resource import, not value import. See more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you're asking **how to import an existing Resource to Serverless**:

I don't have an extensive experience with AWS and Serverless Framework as of today (I started adopting them quite recently), but to my knowledge, importing an existing AWS Resource is not that easy.

I recently had to add an existing, manually-created DynamoDB table to Serverless (SLS) without impacting the data in it. The idea sounded straightforward until I had the following message when I hit `sls deploy`:

`Resource of type 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table' with identifier 'myTable' already exists.`

Serverless Framework employs CloudFormation Stacks for deployments under the hood so I focused there and finally found a solution in AWS Docs.

[AWS Docs: Importing existing resources into stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html)

**I'd highly recommend doing this manual process in pair and you might also want to make sure that no one is modifying the Stack and the Resources in parallel.**

Here's what I've done:

Imagine below `serverless.yml`

```yaml
service: aws-node-project-1
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  runtime: nodejs18.x

functions:
  function1:
    handler: index.handler

# The above was already deployed successfully.

# resources: # Here is the Resource we can't add to Serverless at this time. 
#   Resources:
#     myTable:
#       DeletionPolicy: Retain
#       Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
#       Properties:
#         TableName: myTable
#         AttributeDefinitions:
#           - AttributeName: id
#             AttributeType: S
#         KeySchema:
#           - AttributeName: id
#             KeyType: HASH
#         BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

###### 1. Get the Stack Template

Once you deploy a Serverless Service, it creates a CloudFormation Stack including the resource that it manages. If the name of the Service is `aws-node-project-1`, and the Stage is `dev` for example, most probably the name of the Stack will be `aws-node-project-1-dev` in default. Below command will help you to get the Stack Template in a `template.json` file.

```yaml
aws cloudformation get-template --stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev --output json > template.json
```

This should look like the following:

```json
{
    "TemplateBody": {
        "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
        "Description": "The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application",
        "Resources": {
            // Your existing Resources in the Stack.
        },
        "Outputs": {
            // ...
        }
    },
    "StagesAvailable": [
        // ...
    ]
}
```

###### 2. Get the Resource description

Get the description of the Resource that you want to import. In my case, it's a DynamoDB table.

```yaml
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name myTable --output json > table.json
```

This should look like the following:

```json
{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            // ...
        ],
        "TableName": "myTable",
        "KeySchema": [
            // ...
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 0,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 0
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 44,
        "ItemCount": 3,
        "TableArn": "SOME_ARN",
        "TableId": "SOME_ID",
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
            // ...
        ],
        "TableClassSummary": {
            "TableClass": "STANDARD"
        },
        "DeletionProtectionEnabled": false

        // ...
    }
}
```

###### 3. Add the Resource to the template.json file

Add the new Resource to the `template.json` file without deleting any of the existing ones. The file should include both existing Stack Resources and the Resource that you want to import.

You will also need to move the content of `TemplateBody` to the root in the file then remove `TemplateBody` and `StagesAvailable` fields.

Eventually, the file should look like the following:

```json
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application",
    "Resources": {
        
        // Your existing Resources in the Stack.
        // ...

        // The resource you want to import:
        "myTable": { // This field name is treated as the Logical Id.
            "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain", // This is to make sure that the table won't be deleted if the Stack is deleted.
            "Properties": {
                "AttributeDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "id",
                        "AttributeType": "S"
                    }
                ],
                "TableName": "myTable",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "id",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    }
                ],
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": 0,
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

###### 4. Create a Change Set

```bash
aws cloudformation create-change-set \
--stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev \
--change-set-name ImportChangeSet \
--change-set-type IMPORT \
--resources-to-import "[{\"ResourceType\":\"AWS::DynamoDB::Table\",\"LogicalResourceId\":\"myTable\",\"ResourceIdentifier\":{\"TableName\":\"myTable\"}}]" \
--template-body file://template.json \
# --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM # You may need such Capabilities depending on your case. Use this field consciously.
```

###### 5. Review the change set

```bash
aws cloudformation describe-change-set --change-set-name ImportChangeSet --stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev
```

###### 6. Execute the change set

```bash
aws cloudformation execute-change-set --change-set-name ImportChangeSet --stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev
```

###### 7. Check the Events.

You should see `"ResourceStatus": "IMPORT_COMPLETE"` if it was successful (Give some time to AWS to progress).

```bash
# In AWS Web Console: CloudFormation -> aws-node-project-1-dev -> Events
aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev
```

###### 8. Check the Stack Resources

Verify that the Resource was added to the Stack as expected.

```bash
# In AWS Web Console: CloudFormation -> aws-node-project-1-dev -> Resources
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev
```

###### 9. Check if there is a Drift

In this stage, you should be able to add your Resource to `serverless.yml` and deploy. But before doing it, I'd recommend to check if there is a Drift with the imported Resource.

To my understanding, the term `Drift` is used to point the differences between the Stack's desired configuration (as described in the template) and the actual Resources state.

```bash
# Start detection. This is a background process therefore it will return
# a `Stack-Drift-Detection-Id` so you can check the status of this process later.
# In AWS Web Console: CloudFormation -> aws-node-project-1-dev -> Stack Actions > Detect drifts
aws cloudformation detect-stack-drift --stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev

# Check the detection status until `DetectionStatus` is `DETECTION_COMPLETE`.
aws cloudformation describe-stack-drift-detection-status --stack-drift-detection-id YOUR_STACK_DRIFT_DETECTION_ID_HERE

# If `StackDriftStatus` is `DRIFTED`, check the Drifts with the following command and resolve accordingly.
# In AWS Web Console: CloudFormation -> aws-node-project-1-dev -> Stack Actions > View drift results
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource-drifts --stack-name aws-node-project-1-dev
```